# jQuery Validator custom method

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

could you take a look at this http://jsbin.com/osolo/ please?

If you enter a letter in Min Age rather than a number then hit submit this validates using jquery validator using a regular expression in a custom validation method, this works but i'm now looking to make it a little more dynamic.

In the custom validation method the line

```
var data = $(element).metadata();
```

grabs meta data from the element being validated, what i would like to do is use the

```
data.validateOptions.regex
```

as the regex to test with (i can't see this being a problem), what i can see being a problem is that if the field doesn't validate, rather than using a message that is supplied when calling

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(name, method, message)
```

i'd like to use

```
data.validateOptions.message
```

as the error message from within the custom method, can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Thanks

OneShot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Alex's answer won't work because strings are immutable in JS.

It's close though.  Starting with Alex's code, if you create a closure containing the data object (or just a message string) and also a function returning the message, you can pass the function as the third argument to the addmethod call.
Like so:

```
(function() {
    var data = {};
    var messager = function() {
        return data.validateOptions.message;
    };
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("perorgproperty", function(value, element) { 
        debugger; 
        //alert('testing perorgproperty'); 
        data = $(element).metadata();
        return this.optional(element) || /^\d+$/i.test(value); 
    }, messager);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a closure?

```
var data = {};
jQuery.validator.addMethod("perorgproperty", function(value, element) { 
    debugger; 
    //alert('testing perorgproperty'); 
    data = $(element).metadata(); 

    return this.optional(element) || /^\d+$/i.test(value); 
}, data.validateOptions.message);
```

As long as the function is evaluated before the message, wouldn't the `message` just be passed in by reference?